# Questions about programming/tweaking/using biological software?

Tags: discussion

We have got [a nice question about PyMol](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/732/how-do-i-get-the-current-camera-position-in-pymol-so-i-can-reuse-it-in-scripts) with some upvotes already.

I just wasn't sure whether these questions belong to our community. It is clear to me that the probability of spotting a person who has some experience with particularly this software is higher among biologists, but in my opinion this is not what we would like the site to evolve into.

Answer (score 6):

I think we should allow this kind of questions, similar to StackOverflow allowing questions about programming tools.

I'd allow questions about usage of biological tools, though programming should still be off-topic. The usual restriction applies, the tools should be something specific to Biology, so questions about your favorite text editor are still off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @biocs and @Mad Scientist in that software should be allowed, but explicit programming questions should be off-topic. I would like to add to this discussion that the end goal must have a biological goal in mind, because I can think of many software suites (eg, Matlab, ImageJ) that can be used for biological applications as much as engineering applications.

Answer (score 2):

This question is of the same category as those asking for help with experiments like "[How can I produce milligram quantities of an isotope-labeled DNA oligomer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/117/112)". (Just because they don't have a pipette in hand doesn't mean they aren't biologists.) They should be on-topic for Biology as much as the questions asking for biological results.